# How to remove Shipping and Payment from one-page Checkout in Magento?

Tags: magento, checkout, onepage-checkout

I Try to rewrite below block files with following functions:

```
Rewrite class Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Billing

    public function canShip()
    {
        return false;
    }


   Rewrite class Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method
    public function isShow()
    {
        return false;
    }

   Rewrite class Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping
    public function isShow()
    {
          return false;
    }
```

My issue is it doesn't go to the next step to accomplish the order

Answer (score 1):

Below link explains how to remove shipping method.

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/17/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-shipping-method-step/

and for payment step refer this link:
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/17/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-payment-method-step/